# Getting WCF MaxRecievedMessageSize exception even after increasing the property value

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, soap

I am testing out a WCF service which is running on the same machine (hosted in a Console app) as the client.

The message packet is a bit large so I set the MaxRecievedMessageSize to 2147483647

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="defaultBinding" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
</basicHttpBinding>
```

The app.config is the console app's app.config which hosts the web service.

But when I make the call from the client I get the same below exception that size is too large and it only takes the older value of 65536. It doesnt seem to take the new value I gave. Is this a limitation of basic HTTP binding?

> The maximum message size quota for
>   incoming messages (65536) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quota, use
>   the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on
>   the appropriate binding element.

Could anyone please clarify? Thanks,

Comment: And does the endpoint you're using actually **reference** this binding configuration at all ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try setting MaxReceivedMessageSize on the client as well as the server.

The value in the server's configuration file concerns the size of requests sent from the client to the server.

The value in the client's configuration file concerns the size of responses sent from the server to the client.

Comment: I only added the Service Reference on the client side. Didnt change config files. I will search if there is a config file on the client too/ Thanks Joe